# onChange for dropdown and timeouts

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu which basically sends some data back to the server via onchange. The data is stored in the database and the primary table using seconds to avoid duplicates. What happens is if I scroll the dropdown via my keyboard, for example, using the up/down keys, my script returns an error because there is a duplicate entry now in the database.

here is part of the code for the dropdown in html

```
onchange="GetmySQLData();"
```

My question is can i just do a setTimeout and would it be correct to use it in this format:

```
onchange="setTimeout('GetmySQLData();', 1750);"
```

If you have a better approach, please feel free to let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following versions are interchangeable:

1. `setTimeout('myFunction()',1750);`
2. `setTimeout(myFunction,1750)`
3. `setTimeout(function() { /* some anonymous function */ },1750)`

What you might want is

```
<script>
var tId = ""; // create a global var
</script>
```

and have
`onchange="clearTimeout(tId); tId=setTimeout('GetmySQLData()',1750)"`

which will only execute the onchange after the user does not change the dropdown for the duration of the timeout, but if the user changes within the timeout period, a new timeout is triggered

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work. I just added the quotes like this: onchange="clearTimeout(tId); tId=setTimeout('GetmySQLData();', 1750);" and it works perfectly so far.

Comment: Funnily enough that is how I always did it until I was told off here at SO ;) Now I always do version 3 except in an event handler due to the amount of code. I changed my example to use quotes now

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to use the setTimeOut then it has to called in the following way:

onchange="setTimeout(GetmySQLData(), 1750);"  providing single quotes aroung the arguments makes it to be treated as a string. and the timeout value is in milliseconds.

Comment: That is completely wrong. If you do NOT use quotes, then the function is executed immediately and the result of the function is then attempted to be executed when the timeout is over.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was thinking of passing the object to the function in which case it will treated as a string.